# anonymous complaint background checking

Tags: job-offer, united-states, india

I got a job offer in a reputable company in USA. I have gone through background investigation (within USA and my home country-India) and everything was cleared and I was reported to be eligible. But still my company security department did not give me security clearance, so my recruiter is unable to proceed with my start date.

The security department claimed that they found a criminal history against my name in India reported by an anonymous party. Also, they noted that charge to be a pending one, and that is why the background agency could not find it (India does not report pending charges, according to them; I have no clue).

One of the investigators at my company called me and asked about this stuff, and I answered a straight 'NO' as I have no clue about any of the above. She noted down my points and told me that she will discuss with the legal team and will let me know the decision about clearance.

How serious is the situation? Will I end up losing the job for no reason? And what can I do in this circumstance?

Comment: If you were charged you would know about it. If you weren't charged and it was just a complaint it wouldn't show up on your record (unless you were applying to become a cop or something). Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I went through the background verification and my employer told me that the agency got a anonymous criminal charge against my name in my home country. I am shocked that's why as I cannot remember of anything like that. My employer told me that they will let me know their decision, but I am really worried if they will end up taking back the offer as a criminal report has been shown up (though that is false).

Comment: Is it possible you have a common name and they have you mixed up with someone else? +1 That it seems odd a complaint (no charges) shows up on your criminal record.

Comment: They asked me the same like if it is a common name and actually it is. So will they drag this case very far and end up giving a NO to my offer? I am really scared.

Comment: AFAIK, in the USA a person can file an anonymous complaint or anonymously report a crime, but there's no such thing as an anonymous criminal charge. What country is this question relevant to?

Comment: The USA only. Whenever I am trying to ask my employer about the details of the complaint, they are just saying I have a criminal record against my name. Then when I am asking about further details, they are saying all anonymous (including name, the place complaint was issued). That is why it is really bothering me whether I can prove my innocence because I have no clue about this complaint. And if I cannot, what if they withdraw my job offer and then I cannot reclaim it, because I have no ground.

Comment: @Bean I think that joequerty was asking what your home country where the anonymous complaint was filed was.

Comment: It's India.....

Comment: So you're saying in India you can file a complaint against ANYONE, they won't even know or be able to fight against it and they get a criminal record? This can't be right, your story doesn't add up

Comment: Can't you try to connect to some legal entities in India and get a confirmation for yourself? Actually try to find out what is it about, as in if it is a complaint about you, this information should be available to you.

Comment: " I don't remember any such case in my entire life." You don't remember? That sounds like a weak statement, like it could be true you actually did it. I would voice a stronger denial if you are certain this never ever happened (I mean hurting a female, not having a criminal charge)

Comment: Voted to re-open, this is quite answerable. Short version for the OP: you can (should) dispute the record, state that it is inaccurate and you have no such record, and ask for written (physical or digital is fine) documentation of what this claim is so you can dispute it if they push further. They can drop the issue as unverified, or they can insist on further proof - this can drag out, yes, but usually this is fixable. If they withdraw the offer because of this they must provide documentation with details in the US: https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/practices/inquiries_arrest_conviction.cfm

Comment: I don't have any idea what you can do in India because I have never been to any of this cases. So I am basically clueless what is happening and how a criminal record has been found against my name. presently I am waiting for the decision. I hope everything goes good, if not, I am going to take legal actions. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: I've done background checks myself in order to screen applicants for a volunteer organization.   To do so, I used a service that specializes in it.    If there was any discrepancy, they should be able to provide documentation.    You really need to ask HOW the check was done, and confront the organization that provided the info to demand evidence.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here for an information, I went through a background check by another agency for other employer just a month ago and they found no criminal record any time anywhere. Can I use that documentation (report) to establish my fact?

Comment: @Bean - Can you provide the information to the company, nothing prevents you from doing that, but if they accept it your evidence that isn’t something we can answer.  However, one cannot have a criminal record, from a anonymous compliant.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. There is one more information that came up recently. I called the background screening agency to know more about the unexpected result twice, and both the times they confirmed that there is "no record found" in my report both nationally and internationally. But on the previous day, my employer mentioned that they got a criminal complaint reported by the background agency in my home country. The total incident is appearing to be too fishy to me. if you please tell me possible reasons for this, that will be great!

Comment: How would we know? This is between the company and their background checking firm. It is unlikely you can do anything. BTW I suggest not using the term "security clearance". That term has a specific meaning in the United States.

Answer (score 9):

You can request a police check yourself (for a fee). Such checks are commonly required for visas etc.

It looks like for an Indian police check outside India you'll need to apply to the local Indian embassy/consulate.

The document you receive will have the details of the charge against you, or if it says you are not known to the police (as you believe it should), then you can use this as evidence with your potential employer (or others in the future, as in my experience the results usually take a few weeks to come back).

Comment: I don't have any idea what you can do in India because I have never been to any of this cases. So I am basically clueless what is happening and how a criminal record has been found against my name. presently I am waiting for the decision. I hope everything goes good, if not, I am going to take legal actions. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: I know that in one country where I used to live, I could go to the police and ask them for a report about me, which would contain _everything_ they have, since I'm asking for it, so there are no privacy rules to obey. In the country where I live now, I would go to the police and ask them how I would get such a report. In India, I would do the same thing. Ask them, and go from what they say.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. There is one more information that came up recently. I called the background screening agency to know more about the unexpected result twice, and both the times they confirmed that there is "no record found" in my report both nationally and internationally. But on the previous day, my employer mentioned that they got a criminal complaint reported by the background agency in my home country. The total incident is appearing to be too fishy to me. if you please tell me possible reasons for this, that will be great!

Comment: @Bean that sounds difficult and frustrating for you, but all I (or anyone else here) can do is speculate about possible reasons they'd behave like that, and that won't help you.

Comment: can it leave my job offer in a questioned situation

Answer (score 5):

You said,

> I got a job offer in a reputable company in USA and am going through background check.

Because you're a candidate for an employer in the USA, the employer must follow US employment law when it comes to background checks and how they impact the selection process. Most "criminal background checks" performed in the US are done via consumer reporting bureaus, which means they must comply with the Fair Credit Reporting Act, or FCRA. Per regulation, this means that the employer must:

- **Get your permission to perform the background check.** It sounds like this has already happened.
- **Explicitly notify you** that the reason you're not being hired is because of information in the report they received.
- **Provide a copy of the report to you upon request,** if the report is being considered as a reason to take a negative action (i.e. not hire you because of information in the report)

Regardless of how the employer obtained the information, **they must be able to prove that they're not discriminating against you,** as someone (theoretically) with a criminal record, unless the criminal record provides substantial evidence that you're not fit for the job. In other words, if your criminal record is totally unrelated to your job, and/or doesn't show a significant issue with you being a responsible and safe employee, they can't use it against you.

There are special cases where an employer may obtain (or try to obtain) criminal history via means that are not covered under the FCRA, but unless you're in a very specialized circumstance or applying for very specialized positions, that almost certainly doesn't apply to you.

For more reading on how employers are allowed to use background checks in the US, you can check the EEOC's website (although for the sake of keeping this a self-contained answer, I've summarized the pertinent info in the bullets above):

https://www.eeoc.gov/eeoc/publications/background_checks_employers.cfm

You're in a bit of a special case as you're an international candidate, so your employer may (or, apparently, *is*) use a specialized international background checking service, which many CRAs do offer. The *method* by which these services obtain data varies considerably from agency to agency and from country to country, but regardless of how the information is obtained, your employer must follow the law when it comes to applying it.

To bring this back around to your specific question,

> What my options for what I could do next?

Right now, there's not much you can do, except seek out information on your own as suggested in @PlayerOne's answer - it would be worthwhile to understand your (potential) criminal record in your home country, or lack thereof. Also, it would make sense to have on hand the (positive) results of prior background checks if you still have them, from other jobs you've applied to.

Keep in mind that your potential employer's desire is to fill the position with a viable candidate. They're not in the business of trying to prove you did something wrong, they just want to know the truth about how you'll perform for them. Employers with experience will know that sometimes things come up wrong, especially on something like an international background check. If you have done your homework and can prove you have a clean history, that will likely make a good impact. If the employer still declines to hire you, and you feel they're not complying with the EEOC or FCRA or other relevant law, you can speak with an employment lawyer and determine what options you have.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. There is one more information that came up recently. I called the background screening agency to know more about the unexpected result twice, and both the times they confirmed that there is "no record found" in my report both nationally and internationally. But on the previous day, my employer mentioned that they got a criminal complaint reported by the background agency in my home country. The total incident is appearing to be too fishy to me. if you please tell me possible reasons for this, that will be great!